# What is the difference between: return a string with string.format() and without string format()?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static string TestMethod()
{
    return string.Format("HelloWorld");
}
```

and

```
public static string TestMethod()
{
    return "HelloWorld";
}
```

I now in second there is implicitly call of string.Format() but **i need a performance** which is recommended?

Comment: The second doesn't implicitly call `string.Format`, it is a string literal.

Comment: Performance wise, I can say with 99% certainty, that the second one is quicker, because it _does fewer things_.

Comment: I recommend the string literal because there is no reason to use `string.Format` if you're not actually formatting anything.

Comment: (1) First, make sure you understand the purpose of string.Format. [This is an introduction in the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#Starting) (2) If you are concerned about performance, you will need to measure your program's performance. It's difficult to prescribe the tradeoff between complexity and various types of performance in a StackOverflow post, because it is often very specific to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

For performance AND readability reasons, always use the second approach (returning string literal) if you don't really need any formatting or manipulation of the string. Not only you save CPU cycles, but also memory.

## Explanation

First example (`string.Format(...)` one), even if it did nothing inside (even though it probably does), it would still return a **copy** of the passed string. This means more garbage to be collected by the garbage collector later in the program's execution. Let's do some calculations in a very primitive way. You are passing a string `"Hello World"`. Each character of this string is a single byte, so 11 bytes in total of wasted memory. Seems negligible, right? Now imagine, this line of code is ran 1 million times. Now you have 11MB of garbage to deal with.

Second example just returns the string without any other actions. Thus, no garbage is generated.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Format` is intended to insert values into a string in runtime, see [official introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#Starting).

`return "HelloWorld"` will not invoke `string.Format` - it will return the string literal directly.

`return string.Format("HelloWorld")` will invoke `string.Format`, which will not replace anything. The compiler might choose to remove this call, since it known the constant format string, but it didn't when I tested. So I suppose this would be slower, though you should measure if you're concerned about performance.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Format("HelloWorld");` calls `public static String Format(String format, params Object[] args)` overload, that does a bunch of things, please refer to [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2975) for more details.

To get a bit of taste, what is happening inside, try this code instead:

```
public static string TestMethod()
{
    return string.Format("Hello{0}World");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
return string.Format("hellow worl");
```

string.Format() has a return value.All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object. the returned object declare and initialize strings direct determined at runtime.

```
return "hellow world";
```

"hellow worl" is immutable .String objects are immutable: they cannot be changed after they have been created. declare and initialize strings direct determined at runtime.